# How does Visual Studio run through my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've recently decided to teach myself how to code (using free online tools like Microsoft Virtual Academy) and I've decided that C# will be my starting language.

As most beginners do, I have a pretty basic question that I can't seem to find an answer to (likely because it's too simple).  I am using Visual Studio and I was just wanting to know how the software runs through the code I wrote.

Here is my guess:  I believe that when I run the code, it will only perform actions from "class Program1" because that is the first class in the code.  Once it hits the end of that block, there's nothing else it will do so it closes the console (or more technically I close the console when I hit ENTER).

Initially I was thinking that it should run through "class Program2" as well, but after trying it and seeing it not work as expected I was led to believe that to have any class function like I wanted it to (other than the first one listed - Program1 in this case) it needs to be called.  Am I correct in this understanding of how VS will run through my code?  I apologize for any mix-ups in terminology as well.  Thank you in advance!

**Example Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm Text!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Program2
    {
        static void Main2(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm More Text!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily test if your assumption about the first class being the entry point is correct. Try swapping the two classes and see what happens. Then take a look at the answer below for an explanation.

Comment: Here's another correction: Visual Studio doesn't actually run through your code. It's compiled (converted) into something else which the CPU runs directly. Visual Studio facilitates that by situation by providing a text editor and ways to invoke the compiler and to launch your program once compiled.

Comment: What @siride said. Visual Studio isn't running the code. The CPU is. Or, by another way of looking at it, the operating system (Windows in your case) is: because it is Windows that loads the program into memory and starts off the chain of events that culminate in your `Main` method getting called.

Comment: Visual Studio is still involved *while debugging* a program.  That's a whole other topic though :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are essentially correct.  By default it tries to find a method with a signature `static void Main(string[] args)` to execute at startup (a return type of `int` and/or no parameters are also acceptable).

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

I say "by default" because you can indeed have more than one method with that signature (in different classes).  If you do so, you receive the compiler error

> Error 1   Program 'c:...\obj\Debug\MyProgram.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'MyProgram.Program.Main(string[])'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

In that case, you can use the compile flag `/main` to specify where execution should begin.

Comment: To add to Eric's point, most of the time you only have one `Main` method in your program. Program execution has to start somewhere, so it makes sense to have only one place in the program where it will start, otherwise it will confuse future developers -- or even yourself 6 months down the road when you've written tons of code in the meantime.